# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in a String

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

I tried to debug this and i cant figure out whats wrong with it.
Im trying to build a calculator but i keep getting this error.

```
  double currentResult = 0;

        int stringLengthStarter = 0;
        int stringLengthCounter = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Appends the numbers to the text box when the buttons are clicked

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Click on the digit 1
        {
            if (clearingTextBoxFlag)
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
            }
            stringLengthCounter++;
            textBox1.AppendText("1");
            clearingTextBoxFlag = false;
        }


 private void plusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Plus button clicked
        {
            pick = 1; // 1 - Plus operation
            currentResult = currentResult + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Substring(stringLengthStarter, stringLengthCounter));
            stringLengthStarter = stringLengthCounter + 1;
            stringLengthCounter = 0;
            textBox1.AppendText("+");
        }

 private void equalsButton_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) // Mouse click on the equals button
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            if (pick == 1) // Plus operation
            {
                checkTextBox.Text = textBox1.Text;
                currentResult = currentResult + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Substring(stringLengthStarter, stringLengthCounter)); // The problem
                textBox1.Text = "" + currentResult;
            }
```

I'm trying to do 1+1= and it gets the execption at this line:            `currentResult = currentResult + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Substring(stringLengthStarter, stringLengthCounter));` // The problem

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Not sure if it solves the problem but you have `stringLengthCounter++` but no assignment. You need `stringLengthCounter = stringLengthCounter++` for it to save the change.

Comment: @shruti1810 System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: @shruti1810 Also " startIndex cannot be larger than length of string."

Comment: @GojiraDeMonstah not helping :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your equalsButton_MouseClick method, the first thing you do is to clear the textBox1, which will set the textBox1.Text to string.Empty. After that you try to make a substring of textBox1.Text, but the length of the string is 0, which is why your method is crashing. It's trying to access an index of the string that doesn't exist anymore.

Try moving the textBox1.Clear at the end of your method.